# Running upgraded version of SQLite (3.8) on Mac when Terminal still defaults to old version 3.6

Tags: python, linux, macos, sqlite

I have a Mac running OS X 10.6.8, which comes pre-installed with SQLite3 v3.6. I installed v3.8 using homebrew. But when I type "sqlite3" in my terminal it continues to run the old pre-installed version. Any help? Trying to learn SQL as I'm building my first web app.

Not sure if PATH variable has anything to do with it, but running echo $PATH results in the following: /usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin

And the NEW version of SQLite3 is in the following directory: /usr/local/Cellar/sqlite

I should add that I also downloaded the binary executable to my desktop, and that works if I click from my desktop, but doesn't work from the terminal.

Any help would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: Homebrew does not link ``sqlite3`` by default (see the note in ``brew info sqlite3``), so that it does not interfere with the system one.

Answer (score 0):

To figure out exactly which sqlite3 binaries your system can find type `which -a sqlite3`. This will list the apps in the order that they are found according to your PATH variable, this also shows what order the thes ystem would use when figuring out which to run if you have multiple versions.

Homebrew should normally links binaries into your /usr/local/bin, but as sqlite3 is provided by MAC OS, it is only installed into /usr/local/Cellar/sqlite3, and not linked into /usr/local/bin. As the Cellar path is not in your PATH variable, the system doesn't know that the binaries exist to run.

Long story short, you can just run the Homebrew binary directly with `/usr/local/Cellar/sqlite/3.8.0/bin/sqlite3`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do after install:

```
brew link sqlite --force
```

Don't forget to start new terminal session after this. You can double check currently used version by:

```
sqlite3 --version
```